# jQuery with jQuery mobile bricks form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am trying to implement a collapsable sidebar with a form (search field and submit button) for my site.

I have referenced as script:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

and

```
https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js
```

However in this combination the form just wont submit, instead it seems to apply the get parameters to the URL and then fires `preventDefault` of some sort.
It seems like I am using an old version of jQuery , however when I tried to update to:

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

I noticed that my collapsable menu wont work anymore and the complete style is broken. Also I cant put it in a fiddle since they are mostly already using jQuery.

**Sample 1** (Collapse works but form not):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="about">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <form method="get">
          <input name="test" type="text">
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Sample 2** (Form works but Collapse not):

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Test form</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page" id="about">
    <div data-role="header">
      <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="collapsible">
        <h1>Search</h1>
        <form method="get">
          <input name="test" type="text">
          <button type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

For the first sample I also tried to declare a input type button instead of submit and trigger it manually using:

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function() {
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Without success.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) mobile version 1.4.5 is only locked to certain older [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) versions and have not been tested onto older versions above [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)2.0

Read more about it here if you need to: http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/.

This would explain why the [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)version 3.2.1 doesn't work with your collapsible form.

Meanwhile on the side of the 1.11.3 version, According to the developer console all you have to do is load up your form on a web server instead of loading it locally on your computer (C:/Folder/.html wont work, you need to use browser extensions like https or http)

I hope this helps you as I myself ain't a professional programmer and can't scratch up a working code for you.

Comment: Ok thanks, this explains a little, however I have tested this on my webserver and locally with the same result \-:

Comment: maybe try downgrading your jquery to a version thats ahead of whats you're using currently but also compatible with the mobile jquery?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I was misjudging.
With jQuery mobile comes alot of automatically introduced features for e.g. submitting a form in the background using XHR request and not reloading the site.

Imho they should make this a little bit clearer as I had a hard time figuring this issue out. Solution is: for `s or 's you DONT want to be loaded in background, add the tag: data-ajax="false" like so:

```
<form action="#" method="get" data-ajax="false">

<a href="" data-ajax="false">
```

Hope this helps someone.